# trigger an animation on click while another animation is in progress

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

Please see the jsfiddle of my work https://jsfiddle.net/a013rn4L/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".two").click(function(){
    $(".panelBody").animate({
    marginLeft: "-400px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

$(".three").click(function(){
$(".two").unbind();
    $(".panelBody").animate({
    marginLeft: "-800px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

$(".one").click(function(){
    $(".panelBody").animate({
    marginLeft: "-1000px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

});
```

Here each click function will trigger only after the previous animation is complete. I want to break the animation and trigger the click function as soon as I click them. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try it https://jsfiddle.net/a013rn4L/3/

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

use .stop() method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".two").click(function(){
    $(".panelBody").stop(true, true).animate({
    marginLeft: "-400px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

$(".three").click(function(){
    $(".panelBody").stop(true, true).animate({
    marginLeft: "-800px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

$(".one").click(function(){
    $(".panelBody").stop(true, true).animate({
    marginLeft: "-1000px"
  }, {duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutExpo', queue: true});
});

});
```